# jqueryui dialog buttons won't work after a return false

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

Objective: form validation before submission

Procedure: When user clicks okay the form validation code runs. If any empty `input` fields, return false. So far, this all works.

Problem: If return false then the next okay or close button cannot access the values of the input boxes displayed/edited in the dialog. The alerts work, but the javascript dies as soon as try to get value of an `input` element.

How can I access the `input` element values after a return false?

---

HTML looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>Company Name*<br />
        <input type="text" id="cn" name="co_name" value="'.$client_data['co_name'].'">
    </td>
    <td>Company Main Phone*<br />
        <input type="text" id="cp" name="co_phone1" value="'.$client_data['co_phone1'].'">
    </td>
    <td>Company Website*<br />
        <input type="text" id="cw" name="co_website" value="'.$client_data['co_website'].'">
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

Javascript/JQuery is:

```
var cn = $('#cn');
var cp = $('#cp');
var cw = $('#cw');

$('#co_label').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    modal: true,
    buttons: 
        {
            Test: function() {
                alert('Clicked the test button');
                return false;
            },
            Okay: function() {
                alert('Okay button clicked');
                cn = cn.val();
                cp = cp.val();
                cw = cw.val();
                if (cn=='' || cp=="" || cw=="") {
                    alert('Fields marked with an asterisk cannot be empty.');
                    return false;
                }else{
                    //Save form data via ajax
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                } //END ELSE
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                alert('Cancel button clicked');
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            window.location = 'index.php';
        }
})
```

UPDATE EDIT:

Thanks to Colleen's insightful questions, I have a better understanding of the problem and have updated the question accordingly. What seems to be happening is that the javascript dies when trying to read the input element values after a return false.

Comment: 1. how do you know it's not firing the close method? Does window.location actually work, or do you need window.location.href? Have you tried putting an alert in there to make sure it's actually not getting triggered? 2. sounds like this is more of an issue with triggering close than returning false, if it is actually closing. 3. Do you have a jsfiddle or a page we can look at?

Comment: Fantastic questions. I added an alert as opening code to all button clicks and the button clicks ARE firing. (Note to self: just because nothing's happening doesn't mean nothing's happening).

Comment: Cancel wasn't working because I had a bit of code in there that I removed from the posted example because I was sure it was not germaine to the question: I grabbed the present value of an input control and alerted it. This works fine before a return false, but doesn't work at all after a return false.

Comment: Ok... do you have a jsfiddle or some other kind of test page? Also, are you checking for js errors?

Comment: Another good idea. When I click the okay button after a return false, Chrome console reports: "Uncaught TypeError: Object fakename has no method 'val'" (fakename was the text that I typed for the company name, inside `<input name="co_name" id="cn">`

Comment: Ok, so seems like what's happening is actually that you're getting a js error that's preventing the rest of your code from executing. Now why you're getting that specific error is another question... at first glance your code seems fine. Hm... EDIT: found it, will make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cn = $('#cn');
```

...

```
cn = cn.val();
```

you declared cn as a js object, and then tried to reassign it to be a String. This might work the first time (not even sure about that) but then later you're certainly going to fail trying to switch back to an object, and cause a JS exception that may prevent the rest of your code from executing.

try:

```
var cnText = cn.val()
```

or something similar. Or just skip the whole assigning `$("#cn")` to a var part.

Comment: I took your advice and skipped the whole process of assigning elements to vars, and now do all var assignments when a button is clicked. Will there be any problem re-running the same variable assignment (e.g. `var cn = $('#cn').val();`) every time a button is clicked?

Comment: That style should be fine. Did that change fix the problem?

Comment: Good to hear, thanks. And yes, you nailed the solution. Thank you - especially for explaining why my "clever" re-use of vars was a problem. It didn't occur to me that the var was changing type.